# How to use HPROF in Apache Karaf for CPU profiling?

Tags: apache-karaf, hprof

How can i use HPROF for the jars present in karaf's deploy ? .For jars HPROF is used as follows:

```
java -agentlib:hprof[=options] -jar MyApplication.jar
```

But how can i provide the `hprof` option for the jars present in karaf as the jars are started by karaf through their blueprint?

Comment: take a look at the documentation:
http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/debugging.html

Comment: I have set the `DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_MODE% -Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,depth=10,thread=y,file=hprof.txt,cpu=times` the dump file is created now

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_MODE% -Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,depth=10,thread=y,file=hprof.txt,cpu=times`.The Dump file will be created now